# How do I fill in values of a column based on multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to fill the values of a column based on multiple other columns and I am confused on how to approach this. Here is a example of the data frame I am working with. Each row represents a person. The women_line column is the index for the woman in the household. The cluster_household column represents whether a person is in the same household. The same cluster_household value means that those people are in the same household. Religion is what religion the person is.

| women_line | cluster_household | religion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | 1 1 | NA |
| 2 | 1 1 | 2 |
| NA | 1 1 | NA |
| NA | 1 1 | NA |
| NA | 1 1 | NA |
| NA | 1 1 | NA |
| NA | 1 1 | NA |
| 1 | 1 2 | 3 |
| NA | 1 2 | NA |
| NA | 1 2 | NA |

So the issue is, the woman is the only one answering questions for the household so only she has values for religion. I want to apply her answers for religion to everyone in her household.

For example: I want the woman's (indicated as 2 in women_line) answer in religion (2) applied to everyone in her cluster_household (1 1) so that instead of NAs for religion, they get assigned 2. And I want to do the same for the woman in cluster_household 1 2. How do I go about this in R?

I tried to do an ifelse and case_when but I don't even know if I am doing it correctly or if that is even the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::fill` with `.direction = "downup"` here after `dplyr::group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(cluster_household) %>%
  tidyr::fill(religion, .direction = "downup")

#    women_line cluster_household religion
#         <int> <chr>                <int>
#  1         NA 1_1                      2
#  2          2 1_1                      2
#  3         NA 1_1                      2
#  4         NA 1_1                      2
#  5         NA 1_1                      2
#  6         NA 1_1                      2
#  7         NA 1_1                      2
#  8          1 1_2                      3
#  9         NA 1_2                      3
# 10         NA 1_2                      3
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "women_line cluster_household   religion
NA  1_1 NA
2   1_1 2
NA  1_1 NA
NA  1_1 NA
NA  1_1 NA
NA  1_1 NA
NA  1_1 NA
1   1_2 3
NA  1_2 NA
NA  1_2 NA", h = T)
```